# How do I write a SQL query to select rows from an ODBC source?

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

I'm fairly new to SQL, and MSSQL in particular. I'm looking for a way to select certain rows from an ODBC data source I have already set up into a table.  Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT 
<somecolumns>
INTO
<target_table>
FROM
[ODBC_data_source].sourcetable
```

I should also mention that the data source is properly configured, and I can import from it with the Import Wizard. Is what I have above possible, or do I need to look for other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you going to be accessing this data source a lot? If so, you might want to look into using a linked server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

If it's just a one time or very infrequent thing then you can use OPENROWSET assuming the ODBC exists on the server itself: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276850(v=sql.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column1, column2
INTO new_table_name [IN externaldatabase]
FROM old_tablename
```

Ok, but you want to pull certain ROWS into a new table.  For that just add a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT column1, column2
INTO new_table_name [IN externaldatabase]
FROM old_tablename
WHERE Name in('Mark','Luke',etc)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.  What does `externaldatabase` represent? Is that where I put my connection string to the ODBC database?

Comment: `externaldatabase` is the connection string to the other database.  Is it on the same server or a different instance?

Comment: My ODBC source is on the same server. What is the syntax for writing the connection string for an ODBC source? Apologies for my ignorance

Comment: No worries, if it's on the same server it would be:
`SELECT * INTO newtable FROM DBNAME.Tablename`
Where DBName is the name of the parent database you're pulling from

Comment: Ah. I think I might have been mistaken.  My ODBC source is a system Data Source. I'm looking to pull rows out of it, and put them into a new table.  What I'm asking is how do I connect to an ODBC data source using a sql query?

Comment: What kind of source is it?  A SQL table? Flat File?

Comment: It's actually a connection to a QuickBooks database using the QODBC driver

Comment: I'm not really familiar with using the driver to connect to Quickbooks, can you export to a CSV file then just import that into SQL?

Comment: I could, but I'm looking for an automated solution.  Also, the table is ~150k rows, so exporting and importing to and from CSV would be time consuming and resource demanding.

Comment: 150k rows isnt that much really, but I see how you want to automate it, sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: Thanks anyways. Do you know of the syntax for connecting to any ODBC source in SQL? Even a general solution would be helpful.

Comment: I usually do imports and exports through the wizard, keeps things simple.  This may help get you on the path:
http://www.depts.ttu.edu/ithelpcentral/solutions/odbcsetup.php